# Showing Total Count in using asp.net textbox and checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have five check boxes when user click's any check box it fetch records and shows it in a textbox1, I have another textbox where user input code and fetch records which also show in textbox1. Problem is when user click's checks checkbox it brings records but 1 more than the original records and it shows no records when user input code and fetch records in another textbox for the first time.

Here is my page load method where i declared count method.

```
 int contacts = txt_contacts.Text.Split(',').Length-1;
 codecount.Text = contacts.ToString();
```

Comment: what is the value in the `txt_contacts.Text`

Comment: it is numbers separated by comma  and i want to show count of that numbers in  textbox whoes id is codecount.

Comment: Well, But I asked for the input value that gave you wrong result, and also I dont find any code that `no records` message. Please provide necessary information if you wish to get answered

Comment: on checkbox clicked number are loaded in textbox1 in the form of 9200000,927434793,and so on... and in another textbox i write code like that 11,0875 when user clicks button below the another textbox numbers are also loaded in textbox1 but count of numbers are not correct.

Comment: As per the separator used in split `11,0875` will consider as two numbers and that cause count mismatch(if I understand your issues correctly)